# Django Rest - how can i return a custom json response when authentication fails?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created a custom middleware to authenticate every get request to an API endpoint that i created. Here is my code:

```
class TokenMiddleware(AuthenticationMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return None
        else:     
            try:
                token = request.GET[TOKEN_QUERY_PUBLIC]
                secret = request.GET[TOKEN_QUERY_SECRET]
            except Exception as e:
                # A token isn't included in the query params
                raise ValidationError(detail=str(e))

            user = auth.authenticate(request, token=token, secret=secret)

            if user:
                auth.login(request, user)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Authentication failed', status=404)
```

Now, instead of raising exceptions or returning an HTTP response, i would like to return a JSON string instead, something like: `{'error': 'authentication failed'}`. I know how i would do that from a standard view, but in this case i need to do it from a middleware. How can i do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JsonResponse`:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def process_request(self, request):
    ...
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'authentication failed'})
```